# Text appears normal in storyboard but is being cut off on iPhone simulator - XCode 11.7

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

I am following a tutorial that I found at https://github.com/appbrewery/Flash-Chat-iOS13

but when I clone the project, and set the main page in the storyboard [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PofdC.jpg)

however, when I run the simulator, it looks like "FlashC..." [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kosMX.jpg)

[These are the settings on the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GdAm.jpg)

[And here are the constraint settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwP0V.jpg)

I can't move on until I understand why this is happening but Google has apparently never heard of this issue before.

Comment: You've given the answer. 52 from the leading edge, 52 from the trailing edge, that's wide enough to show the whole text on the big phone you're using in the storyboard but not enough to show the whole text on the little phone you're using in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks Matt, so now that I have it set around 33 it works.  I suppose there is likely a way to have it scale relatively depending on each screen (would hate for an ipad to keep the same text size as a small screen for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the text/logo is too big for the iPhone Screen (which I assume is an iPhone SE or similar)

You can see that when selecting iPhone SE on the storyboard preview, the same happens: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OnXl.png)

The problem here is that there is a constraint aligning the Logo 52 from the Leading to the Superview (Left spacing), you can fix it by changing it to bigger or equal to 33 (33 is enough). Like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I tried setting the Align Leading to: Safe Area >= 33 and it worked!  But when it was 52 it didn't.  Do you know why the 19 (pixel?) difference results in such a drastic cutoff?

Comment: The iPhone SE screen is mucha smaller than the “regular” just 750 pixels while the iPhone 11 has 828 pixels width. Taking into account they are both retina, you have 78/2 more pixels on the iPhone 11